# AWS DMS - what is best way to replicate fewer fields from RDS MySQL to AWS S3

Tags: include, schema, dms

I want to setup my DMS replication task such that I only want to replicated 5 of the 100 source columns (from RDS MySQL source end-point to AWS S3 target).

1. Can I just only mention the column names (col1, col2, col3, col4 and col5) that I want to replicate in the task without mentioning 'exclude' or other 95 columns ?
2. Does the above mean that my DMS tasks are insulated from the source schema changes ? Does my replication break if there was addition of field 101 to the Source table ?

Thanks for your help
regards, Balki

Dont have access to the DMS to be able to trail out.
I could see that INCLDUE fields have where conditions ... would be nice to avoid mention of where condition as I would need any data in the included fields.